# React native simple background task

Tags: android, react-native

As I saw, most of the information about this is pretty old.. I wonder if something has changed.

I want to run a simple background job which handles local notifications that the user should receive once a day.
The job shouldn't run too frequently, just enough to handle this daily notification. 
The reason that I'm not using [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) repeating notifications is because I might want to change the timing or delay notifications, which is not really supported out of the box and requires some background job.

What is the correct way to do this?

- I tried [react-native-background-job](https://github.com/vikeri/react-native-background-job) but it seems that the app is crashes when the job is starting.
- [Headless JS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/headless-js-android) seems to be the feature I'm looking for, but there is not any proper example for this simple case.

How come is that doing such a simple and basic thing, turns to be that complicated?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [react-native-background-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-background-fetch) library to run background app even after kill to it.
It is also using **headless Js** to run task in background.

Comment: Why do I have 2 options for a callback? first in configure, and the other with Headless JS? Which one should I really use?

Comment: you should use only react-native-background-fetch but if you want to run your app in the background after app kills from memory then, in this case, the library uses headless js to execute your headless javascript function and for that, you have to only register your js function in App index.js file. that's it library will take care of every thing in background. hope it will help to understand this.

Comment: So if I want to have my function to run after the app is killed, I should register it twice? At configure and as Headless JS task?

Comment: No not twice, only in headless js.

Comment: What is the correct way to schedule the task for a fixed time once a day? Say every day at 02:00

Comment: Can I use this for calling a function or is it just for fetching?

Comment: There are few predefined functions that you can access while the app is in the background or foreground.It is basically used to connect react-native to native platfroms(android, ios) through bridge. Just go through the docs.

Comment: @AnkitDubey am using this react-native-background-fetch to perform a certain functionality ..but am stuck with this error  registerTask failed to find BackgroundFetchConfig for taskId react-native-background-fetch ... have you faced this